# What is a "Live IP Address"?

Tags: ip-address, terminology

What is a "Live IP Address"?

For example, what does it mean when someone says "I transferred my project from place A to B through a Live IP"?

Comment: Never heard that, either. Besides an extension for Firefox, Google does not found many uses.

Answer (score 4):

Development, especially of web-sites, frequently takes place on a test-machine or a test-network.  This will be on an internal subnet, sometimes with databases, resources, scalability and failover not available, faked, or stubbed out.

When the system is ready for deployment, it is transferred to a Live IP Address, meaning it is visible to the world, has a real database, and other real resources ready to support it.

I dispute the phrase "to B through a Live IP".   I think it is more likely "from A to B onto a Live IP", meaning that "A" was a test/development setup, and "B" is a real-world, or "Live" setup.

Comment: Maybe he really copied the data over a public server to another private place.

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard that term before.  Maybe it means they moved their HTML/images/server-side code from a development/QA machine behind the firewall to a publicly-accessible server?

Answer (score 1):

"LIVE IP" is nothing but just to connect your Premises virtual machines to the outside world. Suppose your Premises IP is something like `60.60.60.6` and the outside world's IP would be something like `192.168.100`.

You can obtain "Live IP" this way:

1. WIN key+R
2. ncpa.cpl
3. double click on "LAN connection"
4. Properties and then select both "Obtain radio button..."
5. and finalize it and note down the live IPs what you got
6. now Select Use the following IP address and insert the IP addresses what you noted down
7. your Live Environment is ready now

Answer (score -2):

I think its just a term, mostly all the network works behind NATs and using DHCPs. NAT binding is mostly temporary, and is refreshed after your new session it begins. As, if your DHCP has allocated you a new IP, or your NAT table entry has expired, you most probably will get a new external IP -- I think by Live IP means using this external IP.

Though a live IP - in your question sounds like a transfer mechanism, i think he might have used wrong english. It can be "to" a live IP, again if i am right, i would not recommend using unpopular terms. As it wastes a lot of time finding out what it means.