# What is the difference between Live IP and STATIC IP?

Tags: ip, ip-address

I came across the terms LIVE IP and STATIC IP and did research on them but couldn't find useful info about the differences between them.

Can anyone please explain the difference to me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A static IP is one that will never change. A dynamic IP is exactly that, dynamic(live ip). It could change frequently, or not change for more than 1 year. It really depends on how the DHCP server that’s assigns the IPs is set up.

Read more: [here](http://www.whatismyip.com/faq/difference-between-static-ip-address-and-dynamic-ip-address.asp#ixzz1VMNfaOXN)

here is the another link 
[http://btbusiness.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/134/~/what-is-the-difference-between-a-static-and-a-dynamic-ip-address%3F](http://btbusiness.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/134/~/what-is-the-difference-between-a-static-and-a-dynamic-ip-address?)

Comment: Thanks man... it made me very clear abt them.

Answer (score 1):

The term live IP address could mean an address that is accessible on the internet. Another usage of the term could also mean if the machine with that given IP address is on the network and responding. See [what is a live ip address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072807/what-is-a-live-ip-address)

A static IP address indicates that the IP address for that network interface has been assigned through configuration on the system as opposed to getting an IP address dynamically from a DHCP server.

Answer (score 0):

Live Ip and Public Ip, both are the same thing. It is used
in the WAN environment, each router gets Live Ip, which is
updated after some time. There is no concern of the end user with the
public Ip.PPP is used for Live Ip addressing.

Non-Live or privte Ip, both are interchangeable terminologis. This Ip is used inside the
network (LAN environment), in which each node gets one specific private ip. 
DHCP is used for Non live Ip addressing.

NAT is basically used for the translation of Non-Live (Private) Ip to Live (Public) Ip.

Comment: -1: How is this answer incorrect? Let me count the ways: Many upstream providers offer static WAN/public IP addresses which will never change. Dynamic IP addresses are issued via DHCP regardless of whether they're public or private, WAN or LAN. Private IP addresses are almost always dynamic; "one specific private IP" for each node is an unusual LAN DHCP configuration. PPP is not normally used to provide IP addresses; it just establishes the connection, then DHCP assigns the address (unless the node has a static IP).